# Value of javax.servlet.context.tempdir set by Tomcat 7 not respected by RichFaces 4.2.2Final

Tags: jsf, tomcat, servlets, richfaces

I'm providing a `<Parameter name="javax.servlet.context.tempdir" value="${catalina.base}/my_temp" override="false"/>` inside the `<Context>` node of Tomcat's `context.xml` file.

I know it's being seen on server start up because of this log message:

```
INFO: Creating LRUMap cache instance using parameters: {javax.servlet.context.tempdir=D:\{omitted}\tmp0\my_temp, org.richfaces.resourceMapping.enabled=true, javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE=Development, javax.faces.SKIP_COMMENTS=true}
```

However, when stepping over code in the RichFaces `FileUploadFacesContextFactory.getTempFilesDirectory()` method, a call to `servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir")` (where `servletContext` is an instance of `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade`) gives the value `D:\{omitted}\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\_`.

I was under the impression (from the [Tomcat Docs on context parameters](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters)) that setting `override="false"` should keep any application from providing an alternative value for this parameter.

Is this expected behaviour?  Configuration error on my part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misunderstand what `<Parameter>` does: it sets a ServletContext "init-param" in the same way that `<context-param><param-name>javax.servlet.context.tempdir</param-name>...</context-param>` would do in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`.

RichFaces is looking at a formal Context attribute, which is different. If you want your web-app to copy an init-param to a context-attribute upon startup, you'll want to create a `ServletContextListener` that executes code similar to the following when your webapp starts:

```
servletContext.setAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir",
                            servletContext.getInitParam("javax.servlet.context.tempdir"));
```

Note that changing the value of the `tmpdir` may not be a great idea: it may interfere with the container's ability to manage your resources.

Comment: I had been uncomfortable with the idea of modifying the value, but felt I was forced to (since the directory was not present during one of my early trials).  I now know that I have other options. Thanks for clarifying the intent of the `<Parameter>` node, Christopher.